# Clojure Core.Typed annotation for apply

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

I'm going through project euler again to develop and hone my core.typed skills. However I am having a ton of difficulty understanding the output of the type checker. I'm asking after reading several introductory materials to core.typed as well as some information on the core.typed wiki.

I am using the following code, and please note that the annotation to `apply`, as well as mapping `num` over the input in function `euler3` has no effect. The error message is still generated. Please ignore the obviously bad `factors` and `prime?` functions. I chose naive implementations to allow me to focus on the type annotations.

```
(ns euler-clj.euler3
"Project euler problem 3.
 Uses a very naive prime tester, would use a sieve or probabilistic
 prime algorithm for a larger problem set.
 What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?"

(:require [clojure.core.typed :refer
          [ann check-ns Int fn> non-nil-return Seq cf]]
          [euler-clj.euler1 :as e1]))

(non-nil-return clojure.lang.Numbers/quotient :all)
(ann ^:no-check clojure.core/apply [[Number Number * -> Number] (Seq Number) -> Number])

(ann factors [Int -> (Seq Int)])
(defn factors
  [n]
  (filter (fn> [m :- Int] (e1/div-by m n)) (range 1 (inc (quot n 2)))))

; Very bad prime function, should be sieve/probabilistic.
; Also identifies 1 as prime incorrectly.
(ann prime? [Int -> Boolean])
(defn prime? [n] (= [1] (factors n)))

(ann euler3 [Int -> Number])
(defn euler3
  [n]
  (apply max (map num (filter prime? (factors n)))))

(ann -main [-> nil])
(defn -main
  []
  (prn (euler3 600851475143)))
```

This produces the following error:

```
Type Error (euler-clj.euler3:26:3) Bad arguments to apply: 

Target:         (Fn [java.lang.Number java.lang.Number * -> java.lang.Number])

Arguments:      (clojure.core.typed/Seq java.lang.Number)
in: (clojure.core/apply clojure.core/max (clojure.core/map clojure.core/num (clojure.core/filter euler-clj.euler3/prime?
 (euler-clj.euler3/factors n))))


ExceptionInfo Type Checker: Found 1 error  clojure.core/ex-info (core.clj:4327)
Start collecting euler-clj.euler3
Start collecting euler-clj.euler1
Finished collecting euler-clj.euler1
Finished collecting euler-clj.euler3
Collected 2 namespaces in 62.584894 msecs
Start checking euler-clj.euler1
Checked euler-clj.euler1 in 165.76663 msecs
Start checking euler-clj.euler3
Checked euler-clj.euler3 in 200.997234 msecs
Checked 2 namespaces (approx. 60 lines) in 430.302357 msecs
```

What type annotations do I need to provide to get apply to accept max and then this seq of numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should not provide your own type for `apply`; it's implemented as a special case in the type checker.

In this case, core.typed needs a bit of convincing that `max` will never be called with zero arguments.

Here's one approach:

```
(ann euler3 [Int -> Number])
(defn euler3
  [n]
  (let [[f & r] (map num (filter prime? (factors n)))]
    (if f
      (apply max f r)
      (throw (Exception. "No prime factors")))))
```

Comment: Hey Ambrose, thanks a lot for the response, the answer was quite obvious once you pointed it out. Haha. I was pretty certain apply had a built in annotation, however I didn't get a warning about duplicate annotations which seems to occur when you try to annotate most core functions. Is there a reason that some do and some do not give warnings?

Comment: `apply` doesn't have an base annotation to fall back on, so any annotation the user adds will probably be the only on that exists. There are a few possible annotations we can give `apply`, each with different pros and cons.