# Clojure core.typed annotation for apply inside a 3rd-party macro

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

I'm using slingshot's `throw+` macro to raise an exception that looks like:

```
(throw+ {:type ::urlparse})
```

The type checker doesn't like it:

```
Type Error (stream2es/http.clj:79:17) Bad arguments to apply:

Target:     [String t/Any * -> String]

Arguments:  (PersistentList String)
in: (clojure.core/apply clojure.core/format (clojure.core/list "throw+: %s" (clojure.core/pr-str %)))


Type Checker: Found 1 error
```

The [macro in slingshot](https://github.com/scgilardi/slingshot/blob/release/src/slingshot/slingshot.clj#L50) looks like:

```
(defmacro throw+
  ([object]
     `(throw+ ~object "throw+: %s" (pr-str ~'%)))
  ([object message]
     `(throw+ ~object "%s" ~message))
  ([object fmt arg & args]
     `(let [environment# (s/environment)
            ~'% ~object
            message# (apply format (list ~fmt ~arg ~@args))
            stack-trace# (s/stack-trace)]
        (s/throw-context ~'% message# stack-trace# environment#)))
  ([]
     `(s/rethrow)))
```

I've tried various `ann ^:no-check` forms on `apply` and `format` and none works.  Since it's a macro, I'm assuming I can't annotate it since it replaces the code that's there. But I also can't rewrite the code in the macro like was suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21254741/3227), because it's in a library. How do I gradually type in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re not able to rewrite the implementation of `throw+`, I suggest a wrapper macro like this.

```
(defmacro typed-throw+ [object]
  `(let [o# ~object]
     (t/tc-ignore
       (throw+ o#))
     (throw (Exception.)))) ; unreachable
;; other arities are an exercise ..
```

This way, you still type check the argument, and core.typed still thinks `throw+` always throws an exception — it doesn't really know that, but the final throw clause allows core.typed to give the entire expression type `Nothing`.

The real answer should be we can improve `apply` to know that applying a non-empty list will satisfy at least one argument, however this answer should work today.

Comment: Totally glossed over `tc-ignore` in recent rereading of the docs!  The wrapper macro works great, will season to taste. Know of any libraries where people have already contributed wrappers for common code like this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is `clojure.core.typed.async`.